# SQL Server - Perfomance trouble while create indexes on a table with 135m records

Tags: sql-server

[image: NO LAPTOP]

I try to create indexes. Yes the table is big (135.8M records). No application running on it actually. I create one after one. Every create needs more time.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[RL_SAP_01]') AND name = N'RL_SAP_01BELEGNUMMER')
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [RL_SAP_01BELEGNUMMER] ON [dbo].[RL_SAP_01] 
(
    [BELEGNUMMER] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[RL_SAP_01]') AND name = N'RL_SAP_01DOCTYPE')
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [RL_SAP_01DOCTYPE] ON [dbo].[RL_SAP_01] 
(
    [DOCTYPE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - Perfomance trouble while create indexes on a table with 135.859.604 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314728/sql-server-perfomance-trouble-while-create-indexes-on-a-table-with-135-859-604)

Comment: Aha. At least a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Let*s get this out.

- The table is not big. It is actually quite small.
- What happens is that likely your computer is just too small. Building an index on a not totally trivial amount of data is taxing. Nothing bad for a proper database server, but these days most people think their laptop's green hard disc is good for a database server.

There is nothing you can do. Check the hardware, your server is likely just underpowered for this operation. Some things in databases take time.

Comment: I see. No one can look inside. SQL Server does what it thinks. Hav a good night I will spend mine take the hand of SQL Server.

Comment: DBCC opentran()

exec sp_who2 151
exec sp_lock 151

Comment: At least I'm suspended by myself

Comment: And maybe you can understand it's not my Server. I "only" are responsible for the application (now not) running on it.